# My 2 month old puppy bit me. He hasn't gotten any vaccines yet, is it dangerous?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, diseases, biting

I was carrying him and talking to him and he suddenly bit me in my face. My 2 month old puppy hasn't gotten any vaccines yet. He just turned two months old last Saturday. Is it dangerous? Thanks. My dog's breed is pug and dachshund mix.

Comment: Related [Regarding bitten from about a 2 month old puppy and risk of rabies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7830/regarding-bitten-from-about-a-2-month-old-puppy-and-risk-of-rabies)

Comment: where do you live? do you have rabies in your area?

Comment: I thought we had a Q&A about what illnesses (other then rabies and Ebola) that a dog might transmit to a person, but I can't find it.  Other than Rabies, I am not sure if any vaccines a dog gets are for things a human can get.  Looking forward to a good answer on this question.

Comment: Dachshunds are biters. They were bred to fight badgers. Be prepared for a lifetime of unprovoked biting.

Comment: very unlikely. just clean the wound.

Comment: I was going to say that you're far more likely to die in a car crash tomorrow than from a puppy bite yesterday, but...four years later and OP hasn't been back. Makes you wonder...

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not particularly dangerous. Rabies is the number 1 concern, but the probability your pug/dachshund mix has the disease is super low. Rabies is transmitted mainly by saliva/bites from infected animals such as dogs, raccoons, foxes, coyotes, etc.

There are other diseases that can be carried by your dog, but it's dependent on your location in the world.

If he punctured the skin, keep it clean to avoid infection.

In the meantime work on the biting behavior - socialize a ton and work on gentle play :) and start vaccines + parasite control.

Comment: I agree with this answer with a strong emphasis on cleaning the wound. Make sure to use soap and hot water, really get in there, use an antiseptic and a topical antibiotic ointment, and cover the "boo boo" with breathability.. especially cover when playing with puppy and don't allow pups to lick ANY wounds whatsoever. But Yes- rabies is low risk in this situation. There are 3 disease causing bacterias that live in dog mouths